# elixir lua calendar showing different behavior while shitf_zone

Tags: elixir

when I clone the repo from `lau/calendar` and try to do

```
iex(6)> {:ok, mvd } = Calendar.DateTime.from_erl {{2014,10,4},{23,44,32}}, "Etc/UTC"
{:ok, #DateTime<2014-10-04 23:44:32Z>}
iex(7)> mvd |> Calendar.DateTime.shift_zone!("Europe/Dublin")                       
#DateTime<2014-10-05 00:44:32+01:00 IST Europe/Dublin>
iex(8)>
```

But in my project when I do shift zone it's not doing the right operation

```
iex(6)> {:ok, mvd } = Calendar.DateTime.from_erl {{2014,10,4},{23,44,32}}, "Etc/UTC"
{:ok, #DateTime<2014-10-04 23:44:32Z>}
iex(8)> mvd |> Calendar.DateTime.shift_zone!("Europe/Dublin")
#DateTime<2014-10-04 23:44:32+00:00 GMT Europe/Dublin>
iex(9)>
```

It's doing everytime zone shift accurately but not for Europe Dublin and also selecting GMT when I do shift in my own project but when I do it in calendar repo `iex`, its using IST.

Please guide me with this problem, Do having `Timex` in the same project can be the problem?

Comment: Having two applications in the same project could not be a problem unless they both use the same resource (like Redis or MQ.)

Comment: I have timex and Calendar. and they both use TzData? that could be a problem? but the conversion has nothing to do with timex.

Comment: Could it be that both projects are using different versions of tzdata?

Comment: Sorry I posted answer by myself its fixed now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in tzdata repository, the issue was with dublin's timezone in a specific version of tzdata. The latest release (0.5.19) has it fixed now. Thanks.